# Preposition + adjective? (for vacant)

Tags: grammar

> Viv shrugged, trying for vacant and harmless.

I’m reading Sun Down Motel and I have no idea how “for vacant and harmless” can work.

Can I use preposition+adjective structure without a noun?

Comment: It's an informal way of saying _trying to appear vacant and harmless_. You could understand it as 'trying for an effect of vacancy'.

Comment: @KateBunting - when I try for wise and clever, my wife tells me I actually achieve silly and constipated.

Answer (score 2):

The writer is expressing, in shortened form, the impression of herself that Viv is attempting to give. Consider it to mean:

> Viv shrugged, trying for [trying to create the impression that she was]
> vacant and harmless.

In standard English, we would not normally follow 'for' with one or more adjectives in this way, but you do see usages of this type in the context of acting, e.g. informal directions to actors (Viv is acting in some sense, even if not in a dramatic production). A director of a stage play, movie, or TV show might say to an actor: 'Give me vacant!',' Give me harmless!' 'Give me scared and surprised!' 'Give me conceited and silly!', meaning that the actor is to portray, by acting, the state asked for. The actor might then say 'I tried for vacant, but it took me five tries before the director was happy'.

Comment: It wouldn't take me that many tries. The director would say 'Great! Thanks Mike!' before I started.